# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at getData

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need a dropdown and I need to get that selected values in console....
When I clicked on the submit button function has to trigger and value has to get in console.
But I am facing the error like:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property addEventListener' of null"

```
<div class="form-group">

                            <select  id ="drop">
                              <option value="volvo">dropdown</option>
                              <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                              <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
                              <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                          </div>


                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getData()">
                            Submit
                          </button>
```

This is the JS code .. I need a dropdown and I need to get that selected values in console.
    But I am Facing the error like:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property addEventListener' of null"

```
function getData() {
        var user = {
          dropdown : ""
        };


      document.querySelector('drop').addEventListener('change', function(user){
               console.log(user.target.value);
      })

        console.log(user);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('drop') // return null this case.
```

to select a element by it's id

```
document.querySelector('#drop')
```

Comment: Error Gone... But I am not getting any selected data from dropdown when i clicked on submit button. Please  help me in this..

Comment: change "change" to "onchange"

Comment: what do you get from console.log ?

Comment: @CuongTranDuc, `"change"` was actually correct. `onchange` is when attached as a property of object or attribute of DOM element. In `addEventListener` param it’s `"change"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="drop">
                <option value="volvo">dropdown</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getData()">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function getData() {
            console.log(document.getElementById('drop').value);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not the most helpful. You should explain what you have done, even if you think it is simple